# From Real into String Variable Conversation

Tags: string, delphi, variables, real-datatype

Please help, how can i convert a real declared variable into a string one. Is there any function like IntToStr() ? RealToStr() function won't work.

Comment: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FormatFloat see if this helps i just googled around :)

Answer (score 6):

There is a bunch of conversion routines in [SysUtils](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils#Functions) unit, ie [FloatToStr](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FloatToStr) and other `FloatTo*` functions. Also see the [Format](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format) function.

Answer (score 2):

A really old method uses the 'Str' procedure, which has two parameters: the first is a real or integer, and the second is a string variable, into which the formatted number will be placed.

Examples:

```
i:= 1;
str (i, a);   // a = '1'
r:= 1.5;
str (r:2, a); // a = '1.50'
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Delphi version you are using.
There is a FloatToStr in newer versions.

Comment: i am using delphi 2009 for this application.

Comment: So it is available. I mentioned the version because there are still people out there using Delphi 5 or 6.

Comment: @KitFisto did u try using FloattoStr in Delphi 6? Because I know its present.

Comment: FloatToStr is also available in Delphi 5

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work...

```
procedure TestConversion;
Var
    StringValue : String;
    RealValue : Real;
    begin
        RealValue := 1 + 1.95;
        Str(RealValue:0:2,StringValue);
        // to display it in a label for example, it should be like this:
        Label1.Caption :=  StringValue + ' is a Real Value!';
    end;
```

so the output should be displayed in the `Label1.Caption`(as example) without problems like this:

`2.95 is a Real value!`